# Getting wikipedia category links

Tags: java, jquery, wikipedia, jodd

What I'm trying to do is get both the categories that are assigned to a certain wikipedia article and the values of the href to the assigned categories.

*Example:*

> Given [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toast) :
>
> "Bread" & "Breakfast foods" are the category
>   names and "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Breads" &
>   "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Breakfast_foods" are the
>   categorylinks

I'm doing this in java using 'Jerry' from the Jodd library to use JQuery in java.

I've used the following code so far to get the category names:

```
File file = new File(SystemUtil.getTempDir(), "temp");
NetUtil.downloadFile(url, file);
Jerry doc = Jerry.jerry(FileUtil.readString(file));
String category=doc.$("div#mw-normal-catlinks").text();
```

Which returns the plain text inside the catlinks div. 
Since this div contains a ul whichs li elements represent a single category it seems more sophisticated to iterate the list-item-elements in order to get the category names & links.

To do that I tried the following:

```
doc.$("div#mw-normal-catlinks").children().each(new CategoryFinder());
```

The idea here is to use a [JerryFunction](http://jodd.org/api/jodd/jerry/JerryFunction.html) object to get the names and links for each child (each requires a JerryFunction as parameter). 
As you may notice I call children() on the div instead of the ul element - this is for lack of a clue how to do that.

How can I make this approach work? Also,is there another way to get the category names & links?

Comment: Trying to parse the HTML of Wikipedia pages is not a good idea. You should use [the API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should use Wikipedia API, but anyway, here is how to this with Jodd Jerry:

```
    File file = FileUtil.createTempFile();
    NetUtil.downloadFile("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toast", file);
    Jerry doc = Jerry.jerry(FileUtil.readString(file));
    Jerry category = doc.$("div#mw-normal-catlinks");
    category.$("ul li").each(
        new JerryFunction() {
            public boolean onNode(Jerry $this, int index) {
                System.out.println($this.text());
                return true;
            }
        });
```

This would print out:

```
Breads
Breakfast foods
```